# How to calculate the portfolio risk and return if daily share prices, volume held on that day is given for all assets?

Tags: finance, risk, returns, portfolio

The problem is with the changing volume of assets which changes the weights. I want to use the formula for portfolio risk but cannot figure out the weights. Should taking average weight of an asset work?

Comment: Can you remind us what 'formula for portfolio risk' you have in mind. Portfolio variance, value at risk, something else?

Comment: Portfolio variance

Comment: The most common approach for a changing portfolio is to compute the portfolio returns (from the stock prices and positions held), then from the times series of portfolio returns compute the variance.